# How to do sum of elements in matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab

```
total=o;
    for j=1:size(Silence_duration)
        total=total+Silence_duration{1,j};
    end
```

But 'total' is empty as[].  If we put total as size(Silence_duration,1) then it is displaying only first value in Silence_duration{1,j}

Comment: What's the value of the variable `o` that you are using to initialize `total`?

Comment: You probably want `size(Silence_duration,2)` rather than `size(Silence_duration)`

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid loops in Matlab; they are much slower than matrix operations.
I think `total = sum(Silence_duration(1, :));` will give what you want. This means "take the sum of the first column of Silence_duration".

Comment: Silence_duration appears to be a cell, therefore OP should use `sum(cell2mat(Silence_duration(1,:)))`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Silence_duration{1,j} is double.
Otherwise try total=total+str2num(Silence_duration{1,j}).
Or whatever value is actually there, if not a string.

Also, size(Silence_duration) will equal 1. Put size(Silence_duration,2) if you want more than one value, which I'm assuming is the reason you wanted the loop.